# Удалить контекстное меню "Диагностика неполадок" и "Центр управления сетями и общим доступом"

Tags: windows, сеть, menu, icon, context

Всем привет, пытаюсь найти как удалить ссылки "Диагностика неполадок" и "Центр управления сетями и общим доступом" из контекстного меню при нажатии правой кнопки мыши по иконке сеть в области уведомлений, нужно редактировать dll или реестр, а где, найти не могу.[image: контекстное меню иконки "сеть"]